# Sorting files in dock folder

Tags: dock, folders, sort

I'm runninγ macOS 10.15.3 (Catalina) and have noticed this behavior.

I have my documents folder in the dock with the following options:

- Sort by: Kind
- Display as: Folder
- View content as: List

The important thing to note here is the first one, the sort by option.
The files in the documents folder are correctly sorted by kind, however, navigating through folders within this documents folder, that sorting just returns to alphabetical.

Within Finder, I have sorting set to kind anyway, but obviously this must be unrelated.

Is there a way to keep sort by kind set for navigating through the dock folder view? Or is this a bug?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  Please [edit] your question to add the version of macOS you're running.  Saying 'up to date' means different things depending on when someone is reading this.